# performance impact of deep copy

Tags: java, clone, deep-copy

I have a complex object that is held in memory and should not be modified. It serves as a template where some of the fields are initialized when the object is first instantiated and some are determined and updated at runtime based on some calling code parameters.

Consider this example:

FooTemplate is an object loaded into memory. The calling code needs an updated version of this object. The updated version has a populated list of service centers. The content of the list depends on some parameters in the client code, in this case caller's country.

```
public class FooTemplate {

    private final String companyName;

    private final String identifier;

    private final List<String> serviceCenters = new ArrayList<String>();

    public FooTemplate(String companyName, String identifier) {
        this.companyName = companyName;
        this.identifier = identifier;
    }

    public String getCompanyName() {
        return companyName;
    }

    public String getIdentifier() {
        return identifier;
    }

    public List<String> getServiceCenters() {
        return serviceCenters;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "FooTemplate [companyName=" + companyName + ", identifier="
                + identifier + ", serviceCenters=" + serviceCenters + "]";
    }       

}
```

FooManager is a singleton that loads the FooTemplate object:

```
public class FooManager {

    private static final FooManager fooManager = new FooManager();

    private FooTemplate fooTemplate;

    private FooManager() {      
        this.fooTemplate = new FooTemplate("ABC inc.", "93746789");
    }

    public static FooManager getInstance() {
        return fooManager;
    }

    public FooTemplate getFoo() {
        return fooTemplate;
    }

}
```

This is the test class:

```
   class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Caller[] callers = {new Caller (CountryCode.US),
                new Caller (CountryCode.US),
                new Caller (CountryCode.US)};

        for (int i = 0; i < callers.length; i++){
        System.out.println(getFoo(callers[i]));
        }

    }

    public static FooTemplate getFoo(Caller caller) {

        FooManager fooManager = FooManager.getInstance();

        FooTemplate fooTemplate = fooManager.getFoo();

        if (caller.getCountryCode() == CountryCode.US){ 
            fooTemplate.getServiceCenters().add("Seattle");
            fooTemplate.getServiceCenters().add("Boston");
        }
        if (caller.getCountryCode() == CountryCode.GER){    
            fooTemplate.getServiceCenters().add("Munich");
            fooTemplate.getServiceCenters().add("Berlin");
        }
        if (caller.getCountryCode() == CountryCode.FRA){    
            fooTemplate.getServiceCenters().add("Paris");
            fooTemplate.getServiceCenters().add("Lyon");
        }   

        return fooTemplate;

    }
}
```

It produces the following output:

FooTemplate [companyName=ABC inc., identifier=93746789, serviceCenters=[Seattle, Boston]]

FooTemplate [companyName=ABC inc., identifier=93746789, serviceCenters=[Seattle, Boston, Seattle, Boston]]

FooTemplate [companyName=ABC inc., identifier=93746789, serviceCenters=[Seattle, Boston, Seattle, Boston, Seattle, Boston]]

I understand that this is happening because the same object is being modified on each iteration. Do I need to deep copy the object before modifying it and return the copy or is there a better solution?

EDIT:
In the actual code the template object is created by parsing an xml, the parsing is done only once, in the singleton. This is why I can't create a new template object every time I need it.

Answer (score 0):

You could just create a new instance of `FooTemplate` every time you call `getFoo`.

```
public static FooTemplate getFoo() {
    return new FooTemplate("ABC inc.", "93746789");
}
```

Or if you don't want to create too many `companyName` and `identifier`, consider calling `String.intern()`. (I think the compiler will optimize the memory allocation anyway.)

If the two strings are constants throughout the whole program, consider declaring them as `static final`.

In general it is not a good practice to copy objects from another while you could just create them from scratch.

EDIT:
Just create a new class `FooCompany`.

```
public class FooCompany {

    private final String companyName;

    private final String identifier;

    public FooCompany(String companyName, String identifier) {
        this.companyName = companyName;
        this.identifier = identifier;
    }

    public String getCompanyName() {
        return companyName;
    }

    public String getIdentifier() {
        return identifier;
    }
}


public class FooManager {

    private static final FooManager fooManager = new FooManager();

    private FooCompany fooCompany;

    private FooManager() {      
        this.fooCompany = new FooCompany("ABC inc.", "93746789");
    }

    public static FooManager getInstance() {
        return fooManager;
    }

    public FooTemplate getFoo() {
        return new FooTemplate(fooCompany.getCompanyName(), fooCompany.getIdentifier());
    }

}
```

Comment: see my edit above. The template object is expensive to create. There are a number of different templates and they are created once and shared across the application.

Comment: Then why is it a singleton in the `FooManager`? Do you mean that there are many instances of `FooManager`?

Comment: No, the FooManager is the singleton, it initializes the template objects.

Answer (score 0):

//you can replace FooManger with below code

public class FooManager {

```
private static final FooManager fooManager = new FooManager();
//if company and contact are fix, make them final
private final String COMPANY="ABC inc.";
private final String CONTACT="93746789";

private FooManager() {      

}

public static FooManager getInstance() {
    return fooManager;
}

public FooTemplate getFoo() {
    return new FooTemplate(COMPANY, CONTACT);
}
```

}